# Porque meu modal não esta recebendo o post

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

Este e o codigo que recebe o post

```
  <?php
 if (isset($_POST['idModal'])) {
          $result = mysqli_query($conn,
           $query="UPDATE tb_cartao
           SET mtpag=Cartão, doc='$_POST[docModal]' , nome='$_POST[nomeModal]', tpdesp='$_POST[tpdespModal]', fornecedor='$_POST[fornecedorModal]', centrocusto='$_POST[centrocusto]', dataemiss='$_POST[dataemissModal]', datavenc='$_POST[datavencModal]', val='$_POST[valModal]', parcela='$_POST[parcelaModal]', banco='$_POST[bancoModal]', cartao='$_POST[cartaoModal]', pag='$_POST[pagModal]' 
           WHERE id ='$_POST[idModal]'"); 
            mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
          ?>

          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Sucesso!</h4>
              O Cartao foi Alterado com sucesso!
      </div>`
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz sentido. Leia o guia de [ask] e veja como melhora-la. Aliás, por que executar duas vezes o `mysqli_query`? A primeira você pega o retorno em `$result` e a segunda você só executa. Tudo muito confuso.

Comment: Obrigado por sua observação